# How to get a token's "pubkey" prior to owning it?

Tags: transactions, python, dex, pubkey

executing the following code using solana's mint address, So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112, I can't get the public key for Solana if I don't have wrapped Solana in my wallet. How can you get the pubkey for a token with which to sign a transaction without already owning the token in your wallet?

```
def get_token_account(endpoint: str, owner: PublicKey, mint: PublicKey):
    account_data = Client(endpoint).get_token_accounts_by_owner(
        owner, TokenAccountOpts(mint)
    )
    print(account_data)
    return PublicKey(account_data["result"]["value"][0]["pubkey"])
```

Comment: You can find associated token account for WSOL mint and your wallet address.